# Shell script to execute python file

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, executable

I am working on a Raspberry pi 4.
Is there an easy way to make an executable file, for example using shell script that execute the prompt commands:

```
 ~/.profile my_profile
 workon my_environment
 cd mypath
 python myscript.py
```

and then leaves the command prompt open?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

Comment: How do  you  plan  to  run the  file ?

Comment: The hope was to initialize and execute my program with one click on a desktop icon,.